# Limitation of Lightning Data Service

Tags: api, lightning-web-components, open-source

I'm reseaching about LWC-OSS and Lightning Data Service.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data

one of the advantage of LWC-OSS is selectable platform, literally.

but there is no info about limitation of Lightning Data Service when use API call from other platform, like heroku.

Can we call Salesforce data from other platform as same as salesforce platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course use Salesforce's full selection of APIs to call for Salesforce data from off-platform.

The direct equivalent of Lightning Data Service, when called from off-platform, is the User Interface API. This is in fact what directly powers Lightning Data Service.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/

Answer (score -2):

Lightning Data Service is currently only available when building on the Lightning Platform.

Check out https://www.salesforce.com/video/7810759/ for some hints on the roadmap #SafeHarbor